# How to implement the given 'for' loop in python

Tags: java, python-3.x, for-loop, range

I am facing difficulties in implementing the following code (which is in Java), in Python:

```
//some code that calculates the values of "r" and "c"

for( int i = r-1 , int j = c-1 , i >= 0 && j >=0 , i-- , j-- ){
    // some code 
}
```

I have tried using 'zip()' with  'range()' but for no good effect.

What would be the implementation if we want to "decrease" both the variables simultaneously but with different values?

Comment: That isn't Java.  Java syntax for the `for` loop will require at least to semicolons.  I suspect you have copied it wrong.

Comment: Your syntax for java is itself wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
for i, j in zip(range(r - 1, -1, -1), range(c - 1, -1, -1)):
    print(i, j)
```

For each case, there are 3 parameters inside `range()`. The first one means `from`, second parameter means `until` and the third parameter means how much to increment/decrement (in this case decrementing by one). That is, `range(from, until, increment_or_decrement_by)`.